# When are qt5 qdom xml nodes deleted?

Tags: qt, qtxml

I would like to understand when qt5 deletes the data of a DOM node.

My first question is: when a node is created (QDomDocument factory method) but it isn't placed in the DOM tree, will it's internal data be deleted (or will the QDomDocument still hold a reference)?

```
domDocument.createElement("test");
// reference not stored by user, element not placed in tree
// may? be held by domDocument
```

My second question is: when the user holds a reference to a single node in de dom tree (e.g. a QDomElement) but no other references (e.g. no QDomDocument), which nodes will be kept alive?

- all child nodes, no parents and no siblings?
- all child nodes, no parents except for the QDomDocument?
- all nodes of the QDomDocument?
- none (you don't hold a reference to the QDomDocument)